# How to deploy a python scraper in the cloud?

Tags: python, scripting, server, cron, cloud

I have some python scrapers (scripts) that I would like to deploy in the cloud in order to make them running from time to time using some sort of a scheduler or cronjob. The problem is that I don't know which platform that can host the scraper and its output for me.
P.S: My scripts are Python based, using BeautifulSoup module.

Comment: Its hard to say without knowing which tech do you use

Answer (score 2):

Using just BeautifulSoup for scrapping and deploying it on cloud is not that efficient and also it will be hard to maintain the code.

I suggest you try [Scrapy](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/) module. If you don't know how to work on it then learn it from their documents. When you are comfortable enough how to scrape with Scrapy then you can try deploying it.

Recently I did one project related scrapping over 10 millions of data and at that time I really wanted to deploy my code to the cloud. After much research I found [ScrapingHub](https://scrapinghub.com/).

You have to create one account there and then one project with Scrapy settings. Free account have 1 free worker which will run for 24 hours only.
Just deploy your Scrapy spider over there and then start your spider. After completion your data will be saved there for 7 days and you can download it in any format like in json.